# How can I specify the format of a picture as a MIME-type?

Tags: raspbian, python, camera, raspicam, picamera

I use a simple code that saves pictures from the picamera as a jpeg.
But i want to save the pictures as a MIME-type, which should be possible according to the API, specifically as a .tiff-format.

Can someone help how to get this MIME-type as output? This is my code:

```
def picture():
    timestamp=datetime.now()
    pc.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/pic'+str(timestamp)+'.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

Picamera does not seem to support TIFF. Here's a list of supported formats from the [documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html):

```
'jpeg' - Write a JPEG file
'png' - Write a PNG file
'gif' - Write a GIF file
'bmp' - Write a Windows bitmap file
'yuv' - Write the raw image data to a file in YUV420 format
'rgb' - Write the raw image data to a file in 24-bit RGB format
'rgba' - Write the raw image data to a file in 32-bit RGBA format
'bgr' - Write the raw image data to a file in 24-bit BGR format
'bgra' - Write the raw image data to a file in 32-bit BGRA format
'raw' - Deprecated option for raw captures; the format is taken from the deprecated raw_format attribute
```

The "support" for MIME in picamera is limited to automatically stripping the prefix, that is, you could specify the format as `jpg` or `image/jpg`. Specifying `image/tiff` does not automatically makes TIFF supported.

Comment: and since TIFF is a metafile format, its contents can include data compressed as LZW (like gif), JPEG, deflate (like png) and none (like bmp) and [many other schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#TIFF_Compression_Tag), it's not very useful to specify TIFF as it can be virtually anything